# swaping external image (load -> remove -> re-load)

Tags: actionscript-3

i can load external png file with below codes from a xml file,

```
function $LoadLogo($Logo:URLRequest,$Target:MovieClip)
{
    var $Loader:Loader = new Loader();
    $Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, $LoadedFunction);
    $Loader.load($Logo);

    function $LoadedFunction(e:Event)
    {
        $Target.Logo.Image.addChild($Loader);

    }

}
$LoadLogo("Logos/logo.png", ScaneLogo)
```

But when i change png's url in xml,  i would like to remove this loaded png from "ScaneLogo.Logo.Image" and  load new png into to "ScaneLogo.Logo.Image" on running time.

Movie Hierarchy as below

**root -> ScaneLogo (MovieClip) -> Logo (MovieClip) -> Image (MovieClip)**

Thank very much already now.

Answer (score 0):

```
//create this variable outside the scope of the function
var $Loader:Loader;

function $LoadLogo($Logo:URLRequest,$Target:MovieClip):void {

//remove all existing children/images from the movieclip
    while ($Target.Logo.Image.numChildren > 0) {
    $Target.Logo.Image.removeChildAt($Target.Logo.Image.numChildren-1);
    }

    //null the existing image loader to prevent a memory leak
    $Loader = null;

    $Loader = new Loader();
    $Loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, $LoadedFunction);
    $Loader.load($Logo);

    function $LoadedFunction(e:Event):void {

        $Loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, $LoadedFunction);
        $Target.Logo.Image.addChild($Loader);

    }

}
$LoadLogo("Logos/logo.png", ScaneLogo)
```